# Does it exist UISlider with value displayed natively?

Tags: ios, uislider

I'm okay to display a label text as soon as a slider value changes, but is there a smarter way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UISlider` as part of `UIKit` has no subview of `UILabel` type.

If you're gonna need a lot of this kind of visual controls you might consider subclassing `UISlider`.

Otherwise just use seperate `UISlider` and `UILabel`.

There are more possible approcahes to this functionality:

You're probably familiar with at least the first one: targeting for `valueChanged` event.

More elegant approach (dabatable) would be Key-Value Observing.

[Key-Value Observing Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000177-BCICJDHA)

Comment: This is what I meant: display an UILabel depending on the value observed. Thanks for the Key-Value Observing concept & the -1

Comment: @gluon: you didn't get the -1 from me - i always leave a comment when i downvote. Here, -1 neutralized. :)